# Field value disappears even if i use keepValueOnUnmount

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

When `useField` name parameter is changed dynamically form property that has the same name as previous `useField` path gets removed from form values, even if keepValueOnUnmount is passed to `useField`.

Is there there a way to prevent this from happening?

Here is a simple example that demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve:
https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-brown-gkoiup?file=/src/App.vue

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <p>Selected question index: {{ selectedQuestion }}</p>
  <button @click="submit">Submit</button>
  <div class="cont">
    <div style="margin-top: 1rem">
      <div
        class="question"
        v-for="(question, idx) in fields"
        @click="selectQuestion(idx)"
        :key="question.key"
      >
        {{ question.value.text }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="selectedQuestion !== -1" style="margin-left: 1rem">
      <h3>Selected question</h3>
      <div>
        <question :questionIdx="selectedQuestion"></question>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useFieldArray, useForm } from "vee-validate";
import { ref } from "vue";
import Question from "./Question";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Question,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const selectedQuestion = ref(-1);

    const { handleSubmit } = useForm({
      initialValues: {
        name: "kkksa",
        questions: [
          { text: "Question 1", description: "sa" },
          { text: "Question 2", description: "sadas" },
          { text: "Question 3", description: "sa21" },
          { text: "Question 4", description: "saeqw" },
        ],
      },
      keepValuesOnUnmount: true,
    });

    const { fields } = useFieldArray("questions");

    const submit = handleSubmit((values) => {
      console.log(values);
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, undefined, 2));
    });
    const selectQuestion = (idx) => {
      selectedQuestion.value = idx;
    };
    return {
      submit,
      fields,
      selectQuestion,
      selectedQuestion,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.cont {
  display: flex;
}
.question {
  background: rgb(197, 117, 117);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Question.vue:

```
<template>
  <input v-model="value" placeholder="Question" />
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { useField } from "vee-validate";
export default {
  props: {
    questionIdx: Number,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const questionTextPath = computed(
      () => `questions[${props.questionIdx}].text`
    );

    const { value } = useField(questionTextPath, undefined, {
      keepValueOnUnmount: true,
    });

    return { value };
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you found the solution for this ?